# Replacing a custom letter-special token combination with text in a File

Tags: java, file, replace, javafx

What I'm trying to achieve is a program that will use a Template of a letter. In the template there will be text like

> Hello Sir/Madam --NAME--

Is it somehow possible to replace the `"--NAME--"` with a `customer.getName()` method? I don't have any code yet but have been breaking my head over this problem.

Comment: There will be no file path neccessary because it will be stored exactly where the code is

Comment: Looks like an X-Y problem. What is it that you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: There will be a File called "FileTemplate.txt" f.e. In that file there will be a standard template for a letter with something like --NAME-- in it. What I'm trying to achieve is duplicating that File and replacing the "--NAME--" with a customer's name via customer.getName()

Comment: yes. You can do it..Look for how to write/update a particular place in  a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it simply by using the **[Java - String replace() Method](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_replace.htm)**, here's what you need :

```
File file = new File("FileTemplate.txt");
String newFile="";
try {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        if(line.contains("--NAME--")){
                line = line.replace("--NAME--", customer.getName()); 
        }
        newFile+=line;
        newFile+=System.getProperty("line.separator"); // add a newLine 
    }
    sc.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**EDIT:**

This code will save to another file, put it after the try/catch:

```
       //Create an new File with the customer name
       File file2 = new File(customer.getName()+".txt"); //make sure you enter the right path
        if (!file2.exists()) {
            file2.createNewFile(); //create the file if it doesn't exist
        }

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file2.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(newFile); // write the new Content to our new file 
        bw.close();
```

See the [**Reading, Writing, and Creating Files Java Doc**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) for further information.

Comment: I tried this, the file is in the bin where the java code is as well (Eclipse workspace). I added a System.out.println("yes") in this if(line.contains("--NAME--"). It does print out yes. But when I then open the File, it hasn't changed the content. :/

Comment: No, this does not write it in the file. I will EDIT my answer so it can save the new contentto another file.

Comment: Now it does copy the text in the File but doesnt replace the existing line. And it doesnt seem to take the enters with it. Is there a way to fix that? The System.out.println("yes") will still execute so somehow the line.replace() doesn't execute or work properly.

Comment: Try to print the line before and after the replace call, and see what happens?

Comment: Ah how Can I miss that !! We have to write `line=line.replace("--NAME--", customer.getName());` instead of  `line.replace("--NAME--", customer.getName());`, it's not assigned to the file Variable, I will Edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks alot that worked for me! Now the only problem is the layout, since the enters won't seem to be copied. Can I fix this?

Comment: Ok I edited the code just add this line `newFile+=System.getProperty("line.separator"); // add a newLine ` and it will work!

Comment: Just one more question haha. It now enters a new Line after every word :/  how can I fix it to be only AFTER the --NAME-- and f.e. after the --ADDRESS-- as well?

Comment: change `String line = sc.next();` **to** `String line = sc.nextLine();`and it will be done. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just read in the File. Then use Regex, or String.replace() or something else to just replace the --NAME-- with the name you want. It's really simple.
EXAMPLE:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<Filename>"));
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
while((line = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    builder.append(line);
}
in.close();
String yourText = builder.toString();
yourText.replace("--NAME--", "Testname");
```

That's all you need